# C# Go through object names with loop

Tags: c#, loops, object

I have a sudoku game, where I want to autogenerate a sudoku, so that the player can solve it.

When I have generated the numbers in the 2d-Array, which I already did, I want to make these values visible to the user by putting them onto the text-property of 81 buttons. The buttons are all named in a similar manner. (sudoku_0_0, sudoku_0_1 etc.- The first number is the x-Coordinate and the second number is the y-Coordinate)

Can I put values on the buttons with a loop?
Like:

```
for(var x=0;x<=8;x++){
    for(var y=0;y<=8;y++){
        sudoku_x_y.Text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a way to do something similar to this?

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your buttons into an array as well.

Make a 2D array of buttons, then do this:

```
Button[][] sudokuButtons = new Button[9][9];
for (int row = 0 ; row != 9 ; row++) {
    for (int col = 0 ; col != 9 ; col++) {
        var name = string.Format("sudoku_{0}_{1}", row, col);
        sudokuButtons[row][col] = this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just loop through the Items/Children property of the element that contains all those buttons.